# "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError" while trying to declare an async AWS Lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

I've had an old AWS Lambda function, that was declared as synchronous (used Promises), the declaration looked like this:

```
exports.getSong = (event, context, callback) => { }
```

It worked as intended. Recently, I decided to re-write it using async/await and thus, tried declaring the `getSong` function asynchronously, like so:

```
exports.getSong = async (event, context) => { }
```

And while trying to execute, I get the following error in it's entirety:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47"
  ]
}
```

It absolutely not clear what the issue is from this error message, but by googling for similar issues and narrowing everything down, I figured out that the problem is the function declaration.

I tried declaring the `getSong` function as synchronous, and then running another asynchronous function inside it, like so:

```
var anotherAsyncFunction = async () => { }
exports.getSong = (event, context, callback) => { anotherAsyncFunction() }
```

But then, I get the same error. So clearly, it has something to do with the Asynchronous function declaration inside the Lambda. What might be the issue here? Thank you.

Comment: looks like you need to add more code for us to debug (ie around line 98)

Comment: I don't have 98 lines of code. That's why I said the error messages are unhelpful.

Comment: is the code above the only code of your lambda?

Comment: your `getSong` function on the bottom bit of code is not async...are you expecting to handle `anotherAsyncFunction` using await or are you going to use `.then` in conjunction with `callback`

Answer (score 4):

I encounter a similar issue. for me it was `res.Body?.toString('utf-8')` which lambda could not understand what is `Body?.` i think in your case you should do the following :

```
export const getSong = async (event, context) => { ...}
```

also for whoever has the same problem, the best way to figure out the reason is to go to your lambda code page, it should show a red `X` on the line of code